# Strange apparent type inference by Objective-C compiler

Tags: objective-c, type-inference

Consider an Objective-C program with the following lines:

```
NSArray *records = dictionary[string];
NSDate  *date    = [records.lastObject date];
```

where `records` is an array of `NSManagedObject`s, which possess attributes `date` of type `NSDate`.

The compiler (in Xcode 6.1.1) gives the following warning for the 2nd line:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing NSDate * with an expression 
of type GTLDateTime.
```

How can this happen? I would not expect the compiler to try any inferences past `records.lastObject` being of type `id`. But it seems to try and arrive at an incorrect one.

So what is possibly going on here?

Comment: Is this literally what the code was, or did you simplify it for the purposes of this question? Can you give us an example where we can reproduce the behavior you describe?

Comment: @Rob Of course I did simplify it. Luckily Aris was able to provide an answer already.

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute `date` be of type `NSDate` for this to work?

Comment: @Aaganrmu It is of type `NSDate`. I was citing `Date`, because this is what it is called in the UI of the Core Data editor. (Will edit.)

Comment: @Drux That's fine, but I disagree with the conclusion. You get the error you report if there is no method called `date` that returned a `NSDate`. But there are several foundation methods called `date` that return `NSDate`. Now, if your method was called something other than `date`, it makes sense, which is why I asked. Or if it couldn't find the foundation methods that returned a `NSDate`, that makes sense, too. But as presented, I don't see how that code sample would generate that error. Glad you solved your problem, nonetheless.

Comment: @Rob The confusion arose because I was not aware that the Objective-C compiler did type inference at all. If it did it the was the Swift compiler does an isolated example like this (IMHO) makes enough sense. Since it does apparently something much more more basic, I can no see why a specific question should cite a wider context. Well, next time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that somewhere is your project there is a method called date that returns a GTLDateTime object. Since .`lastObject` is of type `id`, xcode searches for a selector named "date" to try to infer the return type. If your code is correct, you should just cast `[records.lastObject date]` to `NSDate` or whatever the correct return type is, then you should be OK.

Comment: Agreed, but more to the point, I believe you only see this error if it can't find any `date` method that returns a `NSDate`.

Comment: @Rob Well, in my case `Record` has a method named `date` that returns `NSDate` (it's the getter for the Core Data attribute) and `Record.h` is included.

Comment: @Rob Without testing again: No, it appears, if you have at least two method declarations, which only differ by return type.

Comment: I don't want to make a big deal about it because your suggested solution is correct (hence the up-vote), but in my tests, the existence of a method of the same name with a different type was insufficient to generate this error. I only see this error if the compiler can find _no_ methods of the appropriate return type. There's definitely something else in play here.

Comment: @Rob I created a test project with 2 classes that have a property date. In one class its NSDate in the second its an NSString. Added the 2 instances in an array and this line generates the same warning: NSString * dateString = [array.lastObject date];

Comment: That's fine, I believe you. But I've done precisely the same thing (I just repeated it again, a third time) in Xcode 6.1.1 and I do not get the error in that situation. The only way I get the error is if I do this exercise with a method name other than `date` (i.e. a name for which there is no method of that name that returns `NSDate` object). Clearly there is something else in play here. Simply having a method of that name that happens to return something other than a `NSDate` object is not sufficient. There's got to be something else, some compiler setting, compiler version difference, etc.

Comment: @Rob it is exactly the same as with Aris and as I said here. Running Xcode 6.1.1.  Ah, maybe you have another problem to get the error: If for nth types the same code can be generated, and if the reference var is `id` there is no error.